# Play! MorphiaPlugin throwing IllegalArgumentException in CRUD

Tags: playframework, morphia

When I try to customize the CRUD's list() function by passing a where clause like this:

```
where = "state in (Punjab,Jammu and Kashmir)";
List objects = type.findPage(page, search, searchFields, orderBy, order, where);
```

I get an IllegalArgumentException like below:

```
IllegalArgumentException occured : invalid where clause: state in (Punjab,Jammu and Kashmir).
```

This I believe is MorphiaPlugin is splitting wherever there is an "and" with this MorphiaPlugin line

```
String[] propValPairs = where.split("(and|&&)");
```

Any workaround for this? How can I escape the word **"and"** in my where clause?
I am using Play 1.2.5 and morphia-1.2.9.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace "and" with "," in your "in" expression:

`state in (Punjab,Jammu and Kashmir)` => `state in (Punjab,Jammu, Kashmir)`.

Comment: Jammu and Kashmir is a single entity! And for that matter even Uttarakhand is a problem. In short any condition which has an 'and' in it is an 'illegal argument'.